# Adding Existing Non-Maven Project to a Maven Project

Tags: android, maven

So I am once again getting incredibly frustrated with maven. I want to incorporated [this library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) into my project. At the moment this library is not a maven project. I want to convert it to a maven project and add it to my project.

Would I be right in thinking that the best way to achieve this would be to add it as a submodule? If yes then how?

I had the idea to write a pom, try and generate the project structure then add in the classes manually. It doesn't seem like a nice solution but I don't know what else I can do.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Hi, have you seen this project which shows how a Super POM ties library projects to an app as a dependency. It is a good example of POM structure. https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/tree/master/morseflash

Comment: yeah, I went off that originally. I already had 1 apklib. I was having problems with building it once I got the library in the project. Then problems with importing it to other modules. It's sorted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use the library as a dependency just do a `mvn install:install-file` and add it to your local repository.

If you want to edit the code and build the project with maven then there is no automated way to convert the project.  Your best bet is to create a standard maven project with the default archetype, move the source into your new maven structure, and create the appropriate pom entries.

EDIT:

[Archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) in maven are a way to define the structure of a project.  There is a default structure, or simple structure, if you are in Eclipse and just say New -> Maven Project you can select "simple project" and that will give you the basic src/main/java, src/test/java and a pom.xml structure.

Comment: whats a default archetype? Should this tool do it? https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes

As I get the follow error Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist

Comment: Edited to add description of archetypes

Comment: I got there in the end. I edited the archetype command incorrectly, that set me back a good few hours